# Select dentro de outro select usando o operador LIKE

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql

**OBJETIVO**

Preciso fazer um select dentro de outro select usando o operador LIKE convertendo o valor do outro select para LOWER, mas está me retornando erro

**QUERY**

```
select *
from tbl_client
where "NODE" like ('%'select lower("HOST") from ahc_msystems where "NODE" = 'UTE:pdo-sc03zdbdam030507:NT''%')
```

**OUTPUT**

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "select" Line: 1

Comment: Me parece que seu comando está erroneamente construído. Você está presumindo que o que está entre parênteses será uma string formada pela concatenação dos '%' com o resultado do SELECT mas não construiu o comando adequadamente. O campo "NODE" existe nas duas tabelas utilizadas? Talvez a função position(substring in string) possa ajudá-lo.

Comment: existe sim, vou testar...

Answer (score -1):

**SOLUÇÃO:**

```
LIKE '%' || (SELECT ...) || '%'
```